# Install Extensible Service Proxy on GCE/RHEL7

Tags: nginx, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

[Quickstart for Endpoints on Compute Engine says](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-compute-engine#running_the_sample_api)

> you need to run the Extensible Service Proxy before sending requests
>   to the API

But it [also says](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-compute-engine#creating_a_compute_engine_instance)

> This quickstart works only on Debian. Make sure you create a VM that
>   runs Debian.

I have an existing GCE VM instance running Red Hat EL 7 that I'm adding this Endpoint to. Where are instructions for installing and running Extensible Service Proxy on it?

FWIW I examined the contents of the Debian package. It appears to be just nginx with custom configs and some extra scripts. If there's no RPM or other way of installing ESP on RHEL7, can I just manually install the contents extracted from the .deb package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions for installing the ESP are implied in [the instructions for installing the Cloud SDK on Red Hat and CentOS](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#yum), since the endpoints-runtime RPM is available from the same repo as is the SDK.

```
$ sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/google-cloud-sdk.repo << EOM
[google-cloud-sdk]
name=Google Cloud SDK
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
       https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOM
$ 
$ sudo yum install google-cloud-sdk
```

Note that the ESP installs as nginx, with supporting scripts and config files, that will replace any existing nginx and any files with the same name, which will overwrite any existing nginx functionality (like proxy, cache etc). It might be best to archive any host-specific nginx configs first, then install ESP, then merge old configs into the new ones installed by yum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work (not tested). nginx in the .deb package is a statically compiled  binary with a custom module that runs fine standalone. Please make sure to place the remaining files (config templates, root CA certificates, start-up script) in the same directories as in the .deb package.

Comment: I have an existing nginx server running as a caching reverse proxy. The nginx.conf configured for several front end FQDNs all registered to its single IP#. Some requested FQDNs are served directly by nginx and by other servers running on the nginx host, other requested FQDNs are proxied with other server hosts as their origin server. I can replace the existing nginx binary with the one from the .deb, and just merge my existing config files (including nginx.conf and the cert files) with those from the .deb, right? The nginx-debug binary should also continue to work serving the old configs too?

Comment: Yes, ESP should work as nginx provided you merge the templated nginx configuration file with your handwritten one. If you look into the nginx.conf that is auto-generated, ESP module is turned on per-location and the  supplied root certificates are used for initiating connections to Google services (Service Control service). nginx-debug must be nginx compiled with debugging on for extra logging information.

Comment: Do you know how to merge the ESP trusted-ca-certificates.crt with the existing nginx certificates? Also, two params in the ESP uwsgi_params differ slightly from the existing nginx uwsgi_params : HTTPS [$https if_not_empty] vs [$https] and REQUEST_SCHEME [$scheme] vs [$scheme; if_not_empty;] . Does it matter?

Comment: ESP root certificates are only used to make calls to Google services, not for the upstream backends or downstream clients. So perhaps, you do not even need to merge them. As for the second question, you can probably choose your values. ESP is not using nginx variables AFAIK (you should be looking at /etc/nginx/endpoints/nginx-auto.conf which is the one used by ESP).

Comment: I need the ESP install to be maintainable on my GCE/RHEL7 server, so I'm going to post this question again focusing on the problem installing it from the yum repo. But the APT method has been useful for doing the research to prepare for merging ESP with my exiting nginx configs. Thanks.